# How to group by a derived column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL:

```
   Select Hours, LastName, FirstName, UUID, 
      Case 
         When DatePart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 Then
            Date - 6
         Else
            Date - DatePart(Weekday, Date) + 2
         End as [Week]
   From Entry
   Where Date between '06/30/2014' and '10/31/2014'
```

and what I want to do is group this by the [Week] column that I created using the Case statement.  Is this possible and if so, how can I go about doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple add the same code in group by with out alias name

Comment: I do that and got this "Column 'Entry.Hours' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: If you don't include the other columns in the group by, you need to aggrregate them instead (i.e. SUM, MAX, MIN etc.)

Comment: But the only place date is used is in the case.  I don't want to see date, only the week that I calculated.  I think if I included Date in the aggregate or group by, it will throw off my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to find the `max or sum` of hours of a employee. So something like this should help you. Keep in mind that columns without aggregate function should be present in group by.

```
SELECT Max(Hours),-- sum(Hours)
       LastName,
       FirstName,
       UUID,
       CASE
         WHEN Datepart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 THEN Date - 6
         ELSE Date - Datepart(Weekday, Date) + 2
       END AS [Week]
FROM   Entry
WHERE  Date BETWEEN '06/30/2014' AND '10/31/2014'
GROUP  BY LastName,
          FirstName,
          UUID,
          CASE
            WHEN Datepart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 THEN Date - 6
            ELSE Date - Datepart(Weekday, Date) + 2
          END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't group by a column alias in SQL Server - you need to group by the expression:

```
Select Hours, LastName, FirstName, UUID, 
  Case 
     When DatePart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 Then
        Date - 6
     Else
        Date - DatePart(Weekday, Date) + 2
     End as [Week]
From Entry
Where Date between '06/30/2014' and '10/31/2014'
GROUP BY
  Case 
     When DatePart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 Then
        Date - 6
     Else
        Date - DatePart(Weekday, Date) + 2
     End
```

Although you can make it a bit cleaner using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (
   Select Hours, LastName, FirstName, UUID, 
      Case 
         When DatePart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 Then
            Date - 6
         Else
            Date - DatePart(Weekday, Date) + 2
         End as [Week]
    From Entry
    Where Date between '06/30/2014' and '10/31/2014'
    )
    GROUP BY [Week]
```

But in either case you need to decide how to aggregate the values that are *not* in the group expression.  `Hours` would make sense to do a sum, but how would you aggregate names and IDs?  If no aggregation is necessary just leave them out of the results:

```
SELECT Week, SUM(Hours) FROM
   (
   Select Hours, LastName, FirstName, UUID, 
      Case 
         When DatePart(WeekDay, Date) = 1 Then
            Date - 6
         Else
            Date - DatePart(Weekday, Date) + 2
         End as [Week]
    From Entry
    Where Date between '06/30/2014' and '10/31/2014'
    )
    GROUP BY [Week]
```

Comment: If I put the non aggregated items in the group by, sql server is pretty happy.  I'll try your solution out.